# What is the use of javax.mail.Session?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I was fixing a class responsible for sending emails. It looked like this (simplified):

```
/* ... */
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", A_VALID_IP_OF_MAIL_SERVER);
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);  

try {
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    /* msg.setFrom(); msg.addRecipient(); etc. */
    Transport.send(msg);
    System.out.println("Sent!");
}
catch (Exception e) { /* ... */ }
/* ... */
```

During my work I set `session` to `null` and to my utter surprise the class still worked fine. It doesn't matter if I pass `null` to `MimeMessage` constructor. It doesn't throw an exception or anything. Moreover, the `Transport.send()` method includes the following lines:

`240    Session s = (msg.session != null) ? msg.session :
 241    Session.getDefaultInstance(System.getProperties(), null);`

So if the session is `null` it just creates a new one using system properties. What is then the purpose of creating a `Session` object at all? Why doesn't `MimeMessage` have a default constructor if it doesn't matter what you pass in there?

I viewed a number of examples of using javax.mail, such as: [example from Google](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail) and 
[example from tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm) and they both create a `Session` object which seems pretty useless. Why would anyone do that?

Comment: That works great until you start using Javamail for a multithreaded application, then that will eventually bite you because System.getProperties( ) is a global object.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What is then the purpose of creating a Session object at all?

The session is the context of how you are going to interact with the mail host.  This includes but not limited to debugging output from the mail host, timeouts, and authentication mechanisms.  If you want to interact with the same mail host in different ways then the session is the object that holds this information.

If a single JVM needs to connect to multiple mail servers you need two different sessions.  This is explained in detail in the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#getdefaultinstance):

> If some other code in the same JVM (e.g., in the same app server) has already created the default Session with their properties, you may end up using their Session and your properties will be ignored. This often explains why your property settings seem to be ignored. Always use Session.getInstance to avoid this problem.

Most JavaMail examples fail the [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq-135477.html#commonmistakes) test.  Try to reference the [JavaMail API sample programs](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples)  `Session.getDefaultInstance` is rarely the right choice for any code. Most code should use `Session.getInstance`.  Including a default constructor for `MimeMessage` would just encourage wrong behavior.

Comment: To add to that...  The support for a null Session is there mostly to provide some reasonable behavior in the case where people screw up and fail to create a Session.